# Try another extension if requested not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm working on an image uploading website and it converts every image file to jpg files but I don't want it to change .JPEG extensions to .JPG so is there any posibility that I can tell the server first check if there is a " *.jpg " file then if there isn't try " *.jpeg " inside a folder via htaccess?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning on multiviews for the image folder by adding:

```
Options +Multiviews
```

That will allow mod_negotiation to automatically try to match a request to a file, so something like similar extensions can be handled this way.